# Scala Regex to parse all String except for String which starts with particular word

Tags: regex, scala

I am little confused how to parse all Strings except for a string which start with "if(".
So basically i want all the Strings except for String which starts with "if(" .
I used `"""^[a-zA-Z0-9\\\s-]*""".r` to extract all the string

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific about what your expression should match and how you are using it? If it is used with`match` it is anchored by default and you do not need `^`. To make sure you do not match a string starting with `if(` add a lookahead `(?!if\()` at the pattern start. Try `"""^(?!if\()[a-zA-Z0-9\\\s-]*$""".r`.

Comment: Unclear what you want - what's in the string it if it's not "if(..."? Given it seems (probably) to just return the string, it might be simpler to use `startsWith` rather than a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You may always retrict a more generic pattern with negative lookarounds:

```
^(?!id\()[a-zA-Z0-9\\\s-]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dR3lV1/1)

Here, `(?!id\()` negative lookahead used right after `^` (start of string) basically means *do not match the string if it starts with `id(`*.